# How to manage undefined return type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Sorry , I am new to Typescript, need to pass the prop to a component after filtering , for that I have defined a simple filter method. I get compilation error saying **'Type 'IMilestone[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'IMilestone[]'**

```
 const milestonesOfActiveGroup = ():IMilestone[] => {
    return studyProgress?.groups.filter((group:IGroup) => group.name === activeGroup)[0].milestones
  }
```

since I fetch and populate studyProgress it can be undefined right. What is the correct way to define this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used optional chaining on `studyProgress`, which means that variable may be `null` or `undefined`. In long form, your function does this:

```
const milestonesOfActiveGroup = (): IMilestone[] => {
  if (studyGroup) {
    return studyProgress.groups.filter(
      (group: IGroup) => group.name === activeGroup)[0].milestones
    )
  } else { 
    return undefined // this does not match the declared return type
  }
}
```

So if `studyGroup` does not exist, you can't drill into it and `undefined` is returned instead.

To handle this case you have a few options. Here's two.

Allow the function to return `undefined`

```
const milestonesOfActiveGroup = (): IMilestone[] | undefined => {
```

Or throw an error if `studyProgress` is really expected to be there, and if it's not there, then it should be considered a bug.

```
const milestonesOfActiveGroup = (): IMilestone[] => {
  if (!studyProgress) throw new Error("studyGroup has no value!")
  // typescript knows that studyProgress must exist from here on.
  return studyProgress.groups.filter((group:IGroup) => group.name === activeGroup)[0].milestones)
}
```

---

Think about what it means when `studyProgress` has no value set, and what you program should do in that case. Then handle that case and typescript should give you a green light.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const milestonesOfActiveGroup = (): IMilestone[] | undefined => {
    return studyProgress?.groups.filter((group:IGroup) => group.name === activeGroup)[0].milestones;
  }
```

You declared that "if studyProgress is undefined or null, returns undefined" (`studyProgress?`), so you should declare the return type with `undefined` (`IMilestone[] | null`). `|` is Union, whose meaning is "It will return IMilestone[] OR undefined".

Answer (score 2):

You could defined it as `IMilestone[] | undefined`

```
const milestonesOfActiveGroup = (): IMilestone[] | undefined => {
    return studyProgress?.groups.filter((group:IGroup) => group.name === activeGroup)[0].milestones
  }
```